# Accelerometer behavior different on iPhone4S vs iPhone5?

Tags: accelerometer, iphone-5, iphone-4, acceleration

I'm using "UIAccelerationValue" to log the accelerometer values into a file. After sending the file by email a rough offline analysis of the recorded data will be performed.
This works well with the iPhone4S up to the maximum sampling frequency of 100Hz and delivers reasonable results.

Recently I got an iPhone5 for testing purposes and it showed a strange behavior. The timestamp information is not constantly rising and far away from constant time intervals between two measurement points. In contrast this is not the case on the iPhone4S. Furthermore it seems that the acceleration limit is approx. 8G on iPhone5 compared to 2G on iPhone4S.

It seems that the performance according sampling is very different on the iPhone5 with no obvious reason.

How to solve that problem on iPhone5?